# Rcpp moving average - boundary error leads to fatal error

Tags: c++, r, rcpp, fatal-error

I use a rolling weighted moving average function whose code is provided below. It is coded in C++ via Rcpp. 
This function works for most times series there is no loop issues or anything like this. I provided below a times series of length 2 that sometimes triggers the fatal error.
I could not find the reason of the error.

Thanks for your help! =)

Here is the R code :

```
# Install packages
sourceCpp("partialMA.cpp")
spencer_weights=c( -3, -6, -5, 3, 21, 46, 67, 0, 67, 46, 21, 3, -5, -6, -3)
spencer_ma <- function(x) roll_mean(x,spencer_weights)

x=c(11.026420323685528,0.25933761651337001)
spencer_ma(x) # works
for(i in 1:1000) spencer_ma(x) # triggers the fatal error
```

I include the C++ code of my roll_mean function below :

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector roll_mean(const NumericVector& x,
                        const NumericVector& w) {

  int n = x.size();
  int w_size = w.size();
  int size = (w_size - 1) / 2;

  NumericVector res(n);
  int i, ind_x, ind_w;

  double w_sum = Rcpp::sum(w), tmp_wsum, tmp_xwsum, tmp_w;

  // beginning
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    tmp_xwsum = tmp_wsum = 0;
    for (ind_x = i + size, ind_w = w_size - 1; ind_x >= 0; ind_x--, ind_w--) {
      tmp_w = w[ind_w];
      tmp_wsum += tmp_w;
      tmp_xwsum += x[ind_x] * tmp_w;
    }
    res[i] = tmp_xwsum / tmp_wsum;
  }

  // middle
  int lim2 = n - size;
  for (; i < lim2; i++) {
    tmp_xwsum = 0;
    for (ind_x = i - size, ind_w = 0; ind_w < w_size; ind_x++, ind_w++) {
      tmp_xwsum += x[ind_x] * w[ind_w];
    }
    res[i] = tmp_xwsum / w_sum;
  }

  // end
  for (; i < n; i++) {
    tmp_xwsum = tmp_wsum = 0;
    for (ind_x = i - size, ind_w = 0; ind_x < n; ind_x++, ind_w++) {
      tmp_w = w[ind_w];
      tmp_wsum += tmp_w;
      tmp_xwsum += x[ind_x] * tmp_w;
    }
    res[i] = tmp_xwsum / tmp_wsum;
  }

  return res;
}
```

Comment: It is probably caused by a segmentation fault due to indexing out of bounds (at least from a first quick look). In such cases, R will simply crash. I doubt the reason is precision of computations. I can't provide more information as (a) I don't know exactly what you want to achieve, and (b) the code is a bit complicated, mostly because of the variable names (e.g. why n and not x_size).

Comment: I agree with @George. Also, for what it is worth, it did not crash for me under either RStudio or normal R, both running on Ubuntu.  But as usual the simplest explanation may win, and that is likely a logic / indexing error.  We've all been there.

Comment: @George I believe there is no segmentation error. I tested the function for all possible size of time series from 0 to 100 including NAs values and it works. Indeed the weirdest part is that R always print the correct result (moving average) before crashing.

Comment: And the first six lines of your R code are just noise. Assume someone using Rcpp has Rcpp installed.  Focus on the bug -- so reduced the problem down til it goes away.  We cannot reproduce.

Comment: I reduced as much as possible the problem. There was too much noise sorry. I hope it is better now

Comment: I actually did it in a loop too:  `invisible(replicate(1000, spencer_ma(x)))`.  Still no error for me.

Comment: Thank you. The error comes from my computer then I guess. Thats even more frustrating...

Comment: @MaxFt  I am not sure if you have seen the answer that has been submitted but it is indeed "merely" a logic error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[A Wild `Index Out of Bounds Error` Appeared!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounds_checking)

You can pinpoint the issue by switching element accessors from `[]` to `()`. The latter has a built in bounds check, e.g. is `index` between `0` and `n-1`.

Running the code with the built-in check gives:

```
 Error in roll_mean(x, spencer_weights) : 
  Index out of bounds: [index=7; extent=2].
```

So, the indices being used are greatly exceeding the length of the vector. Adding a trace statement indicates its the first loop that is wrong.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector roll_mean(const NumericVector& x,
                        const NumericVector& w) {

  int n = x.size();
  int w_size = w.size();
  int size = (w_size - 1) / 2;

  Rcpp::Rcout << n << ", w_size: " << w_size << ", size: " << size << std::endl;

  NumericVector res(n);
  int i, ind_x, ind_w;

  double w_sum = Rcpp::sum(w), tmp_wsum, tmp_xwsum, tmp_w;

  // beginning
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    tmp_xwsum = tmp_wsum = 0;

    // Fix this line
    for (ind_x = i + size, ind_w = w_size - 1; ind_x >= 0; ind_x--, ind_w--) { 
      tmp_w = w(ind_w);
      Rcpp::Rcout << "Loop at: " << ind_w << std::endl;
      tmp_wsum += tmp_w;
      tmp_xwsum += x(ind_x) * tmp_w;
    }

    res(i) = tmp_xwsum / tmp_wsum;
  }

  Rcpp::Rcout << "success" << std::endl;
  return res;
}
```

And that's all folks!

Comment: And @coatless wins again with the enforced bounds check :)

Comment: Thank you! you're right the loop does not work if my time series is smaller than the weights vector. I will try to solve the issue and not slow my function too much